# How to drop hive partitions with setting limit

Tags: hive

I have a drop alter query , i want to set limit for it.

Query is :

```
alter table dim_known_hosts drop if exists PARTITION (dimensional_partition_folder<'2016_01_04_00_30');
```

It drops all partition less than `2016_01_04_00_30`.
I want to delete just first `10`.